# How to select one of GWT CellTree nodes after first data fetch?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to select first root node of the CellTree after asynchronous data fetching from server. Here is my code:

```
public class MyTreeModel implements TreeViewModel{

private MyServiceAsync myService = GWT.create(MyService.class);

    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {

        Cell<MyTO> cell = new AbstractCell<MyTO>() {
            @Override
            public void render(Context context, MyTO value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                //rendering node...
            }
        };

        return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyTO>(value instanceof MyTO ?
                createBranchDataProvider((MyTO)value) : //fetching child nodes
                cerateRootDataProvider(), cell); //fetching root nodes
    }

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {

    if (value instanceof MyTO) {
        MyTO to = (MyTO)value;
        return to.isLeafNode();
    }
    return false;
}

private AbstractDataProvider<MyTO> cerateRootDataProvider() {
    AsyncDataProvider<MyTO> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<MyTO>() {
        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<MyTO> display) {
            AsyncCallback<List<MyTO>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<MyTO>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<MyTO> result) {
                    updateRowCount(result.size(), true);
                    updateRowData(0, result);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert(caught.toString());
                }
            };
            myService.getRootNodes(callback);
        }
    };

    return dataProvider;
}

private AbstractDataProvider<MyTO> createBranchDataProvider(final MyTO value) {
    AsyncDataProvider<MyTO> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<MyTO>() {
        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<MyTO> display) {
            AsyncCallback<List<MyTO>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<MyTO>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<MyTO> result) {
                    updateRowCount(result.size(), true);
                    updateRowData(0, result);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert(caught.toString());
                }
            };
            myService.getChildNodes(value.getId(), callback);
        }
    };
    return dataProvider;
}
```

For data which stored on client side solution looks pretty simple: we could just call something like

```
tree.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, true, true);
```

but if we want to fetch data asynchronously we will catch IndexOutOfBoundsException in case we try the same immediately after creation tree, because data is not obtained yet. How can I know when onSuccess() event will be fired in cerateRootDataProvider()? Or I could use another solution? Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options for calling

```
tree.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, true, true);
```

in a right moment:

1. Direct dependency on presenter: add a constructor for your `MyTreeModel` object. Send corresponding presenter as a parameter. Add and call something like `presenter.onDataLoadingComplete()` at the end of `onSuccess` method.
2. Custom event: create your custom event. Fire it at the end of `onSuccess` method. Subscribe to it in some place where you can call access `tree``object. Call necessary code.